# Bootstrap slider is not visable

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-slider

I am trying to use this bootstrap slider on a site I'm developing and its not displaying at all: [slinder](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)
I created a plunker here to demonstrate the issue: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/msKlM1wYmm7QIiksuuQb) Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="14"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

css

```
#ex1Slider .slider-selection {
    background: #BABABA;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var slider = new Slider('#ex1', {
    formatter: function(value) {
        return 'Current value: ' + value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need the stylesheet that comes with the package. Add this to your head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" />
```